# EntityFramework database vs model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I understand the fact that generating a model based on the DataBaseFirst method woill produce a collection of entitites on the ORM that are essentially mapped to the DB tables.

It is my understanding, that if you need properties from other entities or just dropdownlist fields, you can make a ViewModel and use that class as your model.

I have an AppDev course that I just finished and the author wrote something that if I understand it correctly, he is referring to change the ORM entities to fit what your ViewModels would look like, hence, no need for ViewModels. However, if you do this, and regenerate the ORM from the database, those new entities that you placed as "ViewModels" would be gone. If you changed the ORM to update the database, then your database structure in SQL Server would be "undone".

Please inform me if my understanding is correct that I simply need to use a ViewModel in a separate folder to gather specific classes and or properties in a superclass or a single class with the properties that I just need and use that as my model....

Here is the excerpt from the author:
EntityFramework is initially a one to one mapping of classes to tables, but you can create a model that better represents the entities in your application no matter how the data is stored in relational tables.

Comment: For database-first MVC with EF you shouldn't need to touch the generated models at all. They are created as partial classes to facilitate this. 

As you rightly mention, any change to the database that requires a regeneration of code will overwrite the changes you make. 

Current consensus on 'best-practice' seems to be an individual viewModel for each individual view.

Comment: Thanks, that was my understanding....

Answer (score 1):

What I think the author may have been hinting at is the concept of complex models.  Let's say, for instance, that in your Database you have a `Customer` Table and an `Address` Table. A one to one mapping would create 2 model items, one `Customer` class and one `Address` class.  Using complex model mapping, you could instead create a single `Customer` class which contained the columns from both the `Customer` Table and the `Address` table.  Thus, instead of `Customer.Address.Street1` you could refer simply to `Customer.Street1`.  This is only one of many cases where you could represent a conceptual model in code differently than the resulting data in storage.  Check out the excellent blog series [Inheritance with EF CodeFirst](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) for examples of different mapping strategies, like Table Per Hierarchy (TPH), Table Per Type (TPT), Table Per Concrete Class (TPC).  Note that even though these examples are CodeFirst, they still apply to Entity Framework even if the initial models are generated from a Database.

In general, if you use DatabaseFirst and then never modify the resulting entities, you will always have a class in code for each table in the database.  However, the power of Enity Framework is that it allows you to more efficiently work with your entities by allowing these hybrid mappings, thus freeing you to think about your code without the extra burden of your classes having to abide by rigid SQL expectations.

**Edit**

When the Database-First or Model-First entities are generated, they are purposely generated as partial classes.  You can create your own partials which extend the classes that are generated from Entity Framework without modifying the existing class files.  If the models are re-generated, your partial classes will still be intact.  Granted, using partials means that you have the Entity Framework default behaviors as well as your extended behaviors, but this isn't usually a huge issue.

Another option is that you can modify the TT files which Entity Framework uses to generate your models, ensuring that your models are always regenerated in the same state.

Ultimately, the main idea is that just because the default behavior of Entity Framework is to map the database to classes 1:1, there are other options and you are never forced into something that isn't efficient for your project.

Comment: After reading about the link, there still is a problem no one is addressing. If you regenerate your model via DataBaseFirst or ModelFirst, your changes will be lost!

Comment: I typically use a superclass with generated models from the DBContext of the ORM. So for instance, if I have a Project class and a Customer class, I will put these classes (plus any ViewModel classes I may need) in a Superclass called ProjectCustomers, for instance. I can then refer to the properties as Andrew mentioned like ProjectCustomers.Customer.Name and ProjectCustomers.Project.Name. I think if you use Complex mapping, you can't define any primary keys or foreign key relationships. Using the prior, these are still intact.